# why does this work with hover and not with focus?

Tags: css

when i hover over .tdi div it shows picture as it should but why it doesn't work when i put :focus on it, i want it to keep the picture shown when i click on .tdi .

```css
.div1 {
  float: left;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.tdi {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.tdi:hover+.hideDiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tdi">

</div>
<div class="hideDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: focus is not for click .. it's for input when you are writing inside them, check this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: The :focus selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.

Comment: can i achieve desired effect using radio or checkbox?

Comment: Focus will not work. use an invisible checkbox.

Comment: yes you can, or add a JS code

Comment: Use the `:active` selector to enable it when you are pushing the button down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to be able to catch `:focus`, your element must be able to be focused via tab or click . form element and links can receive/catch the focus event, other tags are not supposed to be interactive.

For any other element, you need the attribute `tabindex` to include it in the list of focusable elements of your document , read about it in the link below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

> The **`tabindex`** global attribute indicates if its element can be focused, and if/where it participates in sequential keyboard navigation (usually with the Tab key, hence the name). It accepts an integer as a value, with different results depending on the integer's value

use the value 0, to not reorder the focusable elements , also mind to update the cursor value to show that the element might respond to click event when hovered.

```css
.div1 {
  float: left;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/400/500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.tdi {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.tdi:focus+.hideDiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tdi" tabindex="0">

</div>
<div class="hideDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not focusable. by default, only form input elements and links are focusable. But if you put a `tabindex` attribute into the tag, it becomes focusable and you can do it:

```css
.div1 {
  float: left;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.tdi {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.tdi:focus+.hideDiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tdi" tabindex="0">

</div>
<div class="hideDiv">
</div>
```